# How to split VIM window to show content and enable command

Tags: vim

I am currently reading a manual about how to compile and run a program. Currently I have two terminals, one terminal shows the manual, the other terminal is where I follow the instructions and type the command. Is it possible to do those two things in one terminal. Just like show two files in one terminal. I want to read the instruction in the left side of the terminal window and type command in the right side of the terminal window. Any advice?

Comment: I don't get what you really want.  what does "type command" min? what commands?  I **guess** you are looking for `tmux`

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Vim question.

Comment: What kind of manual? Is this a man page? If it is a man page you may want to create a split and use `:Man` to view the man page. See `:h :Man` for more help on viewing man pages inside of vim.

Comment: Many of us vim users run multiple terminal windows and switch between them with quick `Alt`+`Tab` keystrokes. This is very fast and simple. There are, of course, other options, but they do add complexity for benefits that beginner programmers likely don't need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your problem, having two terminal emulator windows side by side is perfectly acceptable. If you *really* want to add complexity to your learning experience, you can try one of these terminal multiplexers:

- [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)
- [dvtm](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/dvtm/)

or, if such a thing exists for your platform, a terminal emulator with split windows like:

- [iTerm](http://iterm2.com/) (Mac OS X)
- [Terminator](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) (Linux)

Answer (score 0):

In VIM you can create new "windows"/panes just type

```
:vnew
```

For vertical window and

```
:new
```

For horizontal window

If you want to know more about windows you can check [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html) or if you want to know more about VIM features you can try [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the following

`:tabe filename` to open a new tab containing filename or nothing for a blank tab.
`gt` to switch and `gT` to switch backwards.

`:sp` to split the current window <kbd>^w</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> to jump down and <kbd>^w</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> to jump up

or `:vsp` to split vertically (so you can read in the left) <kbd>^w</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> to jump left and <kbd>^w</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> to jump right

all key strokes are in command mode